# Why shared_locked introduced before shared_mutex

Tags: c++, locking, c++14, c++17, mutex

In C++14 there is [`shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) as [reader-writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). This you must use in conjunction with [`shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex). Example:

```
// my shared data
std::shared_mutex mut;
Data data;

void process_data(const Data *); // read-only function
void update_data(Data *);

// multiple threads can read data
void read_data(){
    std::shared_lock lk(mut);
    process_data(&data);
}

// only one thread can read data
void write_data(){
    std::unique_lock lk(mut); // exclusive lock
    update_data(&data);
}
```

As long as I understand `shared_mutex` was introduced in **C++17**, later than `shared_lock` was introduced in **C++14**. You cannot use `shared_lock` without `shared_mutex`.

Why was `shared_locked` introduced in C++14 if there was no `shared_mutex` at that time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++14, there was `std::shared_timed_mutex`, which provides the same facilities as `std::shared_mutex`, *with the addition of extra functions to support timeouts on the locks*.

You could therefore use `std::shared_lock` with `std::shared_timed_mutex` just fine.

Initially it was believed that this was all that was required, but then implementors pointed out that they could make performance improvements by omitting the timeout functions, so `std::shared_mutex` was added as a separate type, but this was too late to add to C++14, so it was added to C++17.